# Symfony error, 'App' is unexpected in Laravel 5.5

Tags: symfony, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel5.3:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'App' (T_STRING), expecting ']'*

I have tried using:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/*
```

But I couldn't interpret the response. Here is the response below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in C:\Users\S Hassan\Documents\projects\laravel\laravel5.5\zera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\S Hassan\Documents\projects\laravel\laravel5.5\zera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('view') #1 C:\Users\S Hassan\Documents\projects\laravel\laravel5.5\zera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view') #2 C:\Users\S Hassan\Documents\projects\laravel\laravel5.5\zera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array) #3 C:\Users\S Hassan\Documents\projects\laravel\laravel5.5\zera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(721): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view', Array) #4 C:\Users\S Hassan\Documents\projects\laravel\laravel5.5\zera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\I in C:\Users\S Hassan\Documents\projects\laravel\laravel5.5\zera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 752

Even a tip in solving the issue will do a lot for me because I am still new with Laravel.

Comment: This could be a permissions issue. Are these set correctly?

Comment: If you're not using docker or something for local dev, try starting with `php artisan serve`. Also the first error is a syntax error. The trace is not related to that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. After using Image intervention, there was a comma I omitted in config\app.php while adding a new item to the providers' array.

Thanks